# using perfect tense before "before"

Tags: past-vs-past-perfect, time-reference

> He abided by all the rules that were explained to him before the programme.
>
> He abided by all the rules that had been explained to him before the programme.

What is the difference b/w the two sentences??
Is it not compulsory to use perfect tense before "before"??

Answer (score 4):

Because before is used it is clear that the explaining of the rules happened first, then the programme started. Because of this, past perfect is optional. In my opinion both sentences have the same meaning.